# ArangoDB export entire Graph to JSON

Tags: arangodb, pyarango

Is there a method for exporting an entire graph in ArangoDB to JSON? Collections work with `arangoexport` but not the whole graph.

```
arangoexport --type json --graph-name templates --server.endpoint tcp://192.168.1.120:8123 --server.username root --server.database testDB --output-directory dumps
```

would return

```
2021-04-08T16:24:53Z [880682] FATAL {config} expecting at least one collection or an AQL query
```

Alternatively - how would you write an AQL that fetches *any* graph?

I would think there should be an easier approach than iterating through all the collections of a graph and download several different collection-JSONs?